# Monster Sound Design

Tags: vocoder

Howdy:)

I would love to find out how to set up [Stout's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d1Z_Rop_iGk) method for monster sound design presented in the video, into Logic 8.

Warmth,
Zuzia

Answer (score 1):

This method is simply using a vocoder with a dog sample as the carrier and the voice input as the modulator.  Logic does come with a vocoder - you can look it up in the manual and here is an article from SOS that looks at it: http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/mar07/articles/logictech_0307.htm

If you are unsure on vocoding in general then details can be found here: http://www.innovativesynthesis.com/introduction-to-vocoders/